# How to correctly setup plugin nvm for oh-my-zsh

Tags: zsh, nvm, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

I'm using oh-my-zsh and I would like to use the plugin [nvm](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/nvm). It works fine, except for one part, the auto switch to correct node version.

I've set the env variable `NVM_AUTOLOAD=1` inside my .zshrc file but it's not working.

Anyone having an idea how to solve that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### SOLUTION

You need to set `NVM_AUTOLOAD=1` before the line:

```
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

I had the same problem when I had it at the end of my `.zshrc`.

### WHY IT'S LIKE THAT

In [the plugin script](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/aa75eeea3348b906f2016be0e44335889e0faed1/plugins/nvm/nvm.plugin.zsh#L42-L65) it only creates the autoload function and adds it as a hook if `NVM_AUTOLOAD` is set. But because this is happening at the top level of the script (as opposed to in some function that's run as a hook or something) it will only happen when the plugin is loaded, and I believe the plugins are only loaded at the line `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`. So it has to be set before that line.

Comment: this is now deprecated. Check this answer for an up-to-date solution : https://stackoverflow.com/a/74549760/5193946

Answer (score 9):

With the latest oh-my-zsh (at the time of this comment), just need to put `zstyle ':omz:plugins:nvm' autoload true` before the call to `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`